# Docker: How to access files from another container from a given container?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, grpc, grpc-node

Basically I have a main directory and Books Directory (General file structure, there's more but these are the important pieces). So when I fire a request from main to booksServer, it doesn't work because the node modules are missing.

That's because the node modules are inside the docker container at a specific path:  **'/usr/src/app'**

How can I have main.js see that books (service/container) does have the proper node packages inside this specific path?

I think I can use docker-compose, but I wanted to test it individually without docker-compose first.

```
**-Main Directory (Individual Service, has its own container)**
  -Initiator (Fires commands) 
  -DockerFile

**-Books Directory (Individual Service, has its own container)**
  -Stubs
     -BooksStub.js (NEED THIS!, but it won't work because needs npm modules which is located in its container @/usr/src/app. How can I access the nodemodules that it's using?)

  -booksServer.js
  -Package*.json (lock and package.json)
  -DockerFile
```

Inside the

**Error:**

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:800
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'grpc'
```

**Books Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:12.14.0
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package*.json ./
COPY . /usr/src/app
RUN npm install
EXPOSE 30043
CMD ["node", "booksServer.js"]
```

**Main DockerFile**

```
FROM node:12.14.0
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package*.json ./
COPY . /usr/src/app
RUN npm install
EXPOSE 4555
CMD ["node", "main.js"]
```

Comment: That looks like you should (correctly) have two separate images, with two separate `node_modules` trees.  Are you missing the `grpc` dependency in `main/package.json`?

Comment: No. This is because in main, it requires a file from the books directory. So that's why there needs to be a shared data volume of some sort. (still a bit unsure as to how to do this.)

Comment: What's the specific file you need?  Where is it in your filesystem layout?  Can you `COPY` it into the `main` image, so that image is self-contained?

Comment: -Books Directory
  -Stubs
    -BooksStub.js
|| 

Main Directory 
  -Initiator -> The initiator needs access to the BooksStub.js file.

But the BooksStub.js file won't work because the node_module is inside the Books Container. 

This is a microservice architecture so the idea was that each service (main service vs. book service) has their own dependencies (package*.json)

Comment: Just edited the file directory on the post as well.

Comment: I keep getting this error, probably something involving async gRPC calls.

Error:
undefined:1
undefined
^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at ClientUnaryCall.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/main.js:119:8)
    at ClientUnaryCall.emit (events.js:210:5)
    at Object.onReceiveMetadata (/usr/src/app/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:1202:15)
    at InterceptingListener._callNext (/usr/src/app/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:568:42)
    at InterceptingListener.onReceiveMetadata

Answer (score 3):

You can create one common `datavolume` and attached your containers with the `datavolume`

Here is the step to create a datavolume,

**Step 1 :** `docker volume create --name storageOne` You can give any name instead of `storageOne`

**Step 2 :** Now you need to attach that volume with the container using `docker run -ti --name=myContainer -v storageOne:/storageOne ubuntu` command

**Step 3 :** Copy or create your required file in that datavolume

**Step 4 :** Now Create an another Container using `docker run -ti --name=myContainer2 --volumes-from MyContainer ubuntu` command

**Step 5 :** Restart your `myStorage` container

So whatever files are available in `myStorage` will be shareable between attached container.

May be this will help you

Comment: There are big problems using volumes for code like this.  Of note, say the file in the `books` container changes in the underlying code base.  Since volumes are supposed to contain user data, Docker won't update the volume, so the `main` container will have an out-of-date copy of the file; not only that, but the stale volume code will probably also hide what's in the image in the `books` containers.  I would not recommend volumes here.